# bxslider bind .next button to next slide in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, bxslider

Have such problem. I try create custom slider editing bxslider. I set classes to active, next and prev `<li>` and I would want that by clicking on the `.next-caption` and the `.prev-caption` li slider did the same thing as clicking on `.bx-next` and `.bx-prev`, that is twisted slider.

Here my js

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideWidth: 350,
    slideMargin: 0,
     moveSlides: 1,
     pager: false,
     // auto: true,
     speed: 3000,
     pause: 8000,
     // autoHover: true,
     onSlideBefore: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
        console.log(currentSlideHtmlObject);
        $('.active-caption').removeClass('active-caption');
        $('.bxslider>li').eq(currentSlideHtmlObject + 4).addClass('active-caption');
        $('.prev-caption').removeClass('prev-caption');
        $('.bxslider>li').eq(currentSlideHtmlObject + 3).addClass('prev-caption');
        $('.next-caption').removeClass('next-caption');
        $('.bxslider>li').eq(currentSlideHtmlObject + 5).addClass('next-caption')
    },
    onSliderLoad: function () {
        $('.bxslider>li').eq(4).addClass('active-caption');
        $('.bxslider>li').eq(3).addClass('prev-caption');
        $('.bxslider>li').eq(5).addClass('next-caption')
   },
});
```

Thanks for any help! See [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CroaToa/kj32f7ks/)

Comment: your code looks to we working fine.What is the problem???

Comment: I want slide carousel by clicking on `.next-caption` and `.prev-caption` li :)

Comment: u mean u ll show 3 items n on left item click u ll slide left??

Comment: @Harsh Yes, you're absolutely right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be useful for someone.

```
$('body').on( "click", '.next-caption', function(e){
$('.bx-next').trigger('click');
});
$('body').on( "click", '.prev-caption', function(e){
$('.bx-prev').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

open the file - jquery.bxslider.min.js

find the function and comment on internal controls

r.stopAuto = function (t) {

//o.interval && (clearInterval (o.interval), o.interval = null && o.settings.autoControls // 1! // && t = A ("start")) 
  }